# How can I iterate through the following directory full of images and add the images to my HTML page

Tags: javascript, html, loops, auto-populating

I want to use javascript to automatically update my index.html doc based on files which are inside the images directory.

Here's a snippet of how the html should look if the directory contained the following 3 image files 'moth_forsale.jpg', 'art_sold.jpg', 'bat_forsale.jpg'.

```
<a class='gallery-link' target="_blank" href='../images/moth_forsale.jpg'>
  <img src="../images_small/moth_forsale.jpg" class="all forsale">
</a>
<a class='gallery-link' target="_blank" href='../images/art_sold.jpg'>
  <img src="../images_small/art_sold.jpg" class="all forsale">
</a>
<a class='gallery-link' target="_blank" href='../images/bat_forsale.jpg'>
  <img src="../images_small/bat_forsale.jpg" class="all forsale">
</a>
```

As shown, in addition to updating the file paths, I also need to update the class, with either 'forsale' or 'sold', depending on what the image name contains.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.gallery-link > img').forEach(img => {
  img.classList.add(img.src.includes('forsale') ? 'forsale' : 'sold');
});
```

if you need to check and remove previous classes, you can use `img.classList.remove()` method.

If you only need to address the image in your CSS you can use [partial attribute CSS selector](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_attr_contain.asp):

```
.gallery-link > img[src*=forsale]
```

use it to get all images with `forsale` string intheir `src` attribute, and

```
.gallery-link > img[src*=sold]
```

for images with `sold`